# heap use after free derivated from a memory leak

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, heap-corruption

So I was testing a function I have it works and all but for some reason, when I use `fsantize` alongside valgrind I get an heap usage after free and there's nothing more after `free`.

error:

```
==18707==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x6030000093e8 at pc 0x55d773ca7cab bp 0x7fffc6cd72c0 sp 0x7fffc6cd72b0
READ of size 8 at 0x6030000093e8 thread T0
    #0 0x55d773ca7caa in main /home/martim/Desktop/projeto iaed/teste de linked lists/teste_todo.c:114
    #1 0x7f78eabb7b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #2 0x55d773ca40c9 in _start (/home/martim/Desktop/projeto iaed/teste de linked lists/foo_3689+0x10c9)

0x6030000093e8 is located 24 bytes inside of 32-byte region [0x6030000093d0,0x6030000093f0)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f78eb0657a8 in __interceptor_free (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0xde7a8)
    #1 0x55d773ca4fc0 in FREEnode_v /home/martim/Desktop/projeto iaed/teste de linked lists/Listas_ligadas2.h:82
    #2 0x55d773ca50cf in delete_el_v /home/martim/Desktop/projeto iaed/teste de linked lists/Listas_ligadas2.h:97
    #3 0x55d773ca7c82 in main /home/martim/Desktop/projeto iaed/teste de linked lists/teste_todo.c:115
    #4 0x7f78eabb7b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f78eb065b40 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0xdeb40)
    #1 0x55d773ca4baa in NEW_vit /home/martim/Desktop/projeto iaed/teste de linked lists/Listas_ligadas2.h:30
    #2 0x55d773ca4db7 in insertEnd_v /home/martim/Desktop/projeto iaed/teste de linked lists/Listas_ligadas2.h:49
    #3 0x55d773ca690c in adiciona_eq /home/martim/Desktop/projeto iaed/teste de linked lists/FUNCOES_AUX.h:296
    #4 0x55d773ca6c1d in A /home/martim/Desktop/projeto iaed/teste de linked lists/FUNCOES_MAIN.h:20
    #5 0x55d773ca765d in main /home/martim/Desktop/projeto iaed/teste de linked lists/teste_todo.c:56
    #6 0x7f78eabb7b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
```

The function I basically uses this `free` functions:

This is the main function used (part of FUNCOES_MAIN.h)

```
void A(char nome[], link_v* head2,int valores[]) {
    int check;
    check = adiciona_eq(nome, &*head2, valores);
    if (check == 1)
        printf("%d Equipa existente.\n", valores[1]);
}
```

This is an auxiliary function used that basically does all the things I want
(part of FUNCOES_AUX.h)

```
int adiciona_eq(char nome[], link_v* head, int valores[]) {
    link_v t;
    for (t = *head; t != NULL; t = t->next) {
        if (strcmp(t->v.nome, nome) == 0)
            return 1;
    }
    *head = insertEnd_v(*head, nome, valores);
    valores[3] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

This is an part of an header file I have for linked lists (this is the only part used in this function and part of Listas_ligadas2.h)

```
typedef struct vit {
    int id;
    char *nome;
    int vit;
} vit;

/*--------- Estrutura que representa um nodo de uma lista de vitorias ------------*/

typedef struct node_v {
    vit v;
    struct node_v *next;
} *link_v;

/*A funcao NEW_v cria um nodo da lista de vitorias.*/
link_v NEW_vit(char *nome, int val[]) {
    link_v x = (link_v)malloc(sizeof(struct node_v));
    x->v.nome = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(nome) + 1));
    strcpy(x->v.nome, nome);
    x->v.vit = 0;
    x->v.id = val[0];
    x->next = NULL;
    val[0]++;
    return x;
}

/*A funcao insertEnd_v insere o nodo criado por NEW_v na lista de vitorias.*/
link_v insertEnd_v(link_v head, char *nome, int val[]) {
    link_v x;
    if (head == NULL)
        return NEW_vit(nome, val);
    for (x = head; x->next != NULL; x = x->next)
        ;
    x->next = NEW_vit(nome, val);
    return head;
}
```

If I confused you, I'm sorry but basically this is my `main` program:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Listas_ligadas2.h"
#include "FUNCOES_PROTOTIPO_AUX.h"
#include "FUNCOES_PROTOTIPO_MAIN.h"
#include "FUNCOES_AUX.h"
#include "FUNCOES_MAIN.h"

#define MAX_CHARS 1024

/*
ident: val[0]
line of stdin: val[1]
*/

int main() {
    char c;
    char nome[MAX_CHARS];
    int valores[2] = { 0, 1 };
    link_v head2 = NULL;
    link_v yf;
    while ((c = getchar())!= 'x') {
        switch (c) {
          case 'A':
            {
                scanf("%1023[^:\n]", nome);
                remove_esp(nome);
                A(nome, &head2,valores);
                valores[1]++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (yf = head2; yf != NULL; yf = yf->next) {
        delete_el_v(yf, yf->v.nome);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide the code for the function `delete_el_v`, I must speculate. My guess is that the problem is in the following code:

```
for (yf = head2; yf != NULL; yf = yf->next) {
    delete_el_v(yf, yf->v.nome);
}
```

I assume that the function `delete_el_v` first frees `yf->v.name` and then frees `yf`, because doing it the other way around would in itself cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If this assumption of mine is correct, then that section of code would effectively be doing the following:

```
for (yf = head2; yf != NULL; yf = yf->next) {
    free( yf->v.name );
    free( yf );
}
```

However, this also causes undefined behavior, because after every iteration of the loop, you are evaluation the expression `yf->next`. At that point, the pointer `yf` is a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), because it has been freed. Therefore, dereferencing that dangling pointer with the expression `yf->next` caused undefined behavior. This is probably the reason why you are getting the "heap-use-after-free" message.

To fix this, I suggest changing the code to the following:

```
yf = head2;
while ( yf != NULL ) {
    struct node_v *temp = yf;
    yf = yf->next;
    free( temp->v.name );
    free( temp );
}
```

Also, your line

`valores[3] = 0;`

is causing undefined behavior by writing to the array out of bounds. The array has a size of 2 elements, but you are writing to its non-existant 4th element.

Comment: so i tried the code u gave and it fixed the heap use after free the problem is that im having memory leaks every time i create a node in my list of struct node_v

Comment: @MartimCorreia: I have now updated my answer at the end to additionally point out that the line `valores[3] = 0;` is causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @MartimCorreia: I am unable to find anything else in the code you posted that may be causing this error. However, you did not post the functions `remove_esp` or `delete_el_v`, so I cannot examine them.